# What is the proper way to do multi-parameter AJAX form validation with jQuery and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a registration form for a website that needs to check if an email address already exists for a given company id. When the user tabs or clicks out of the email field (blur event), I want jQuery to go off and do an AJAX request so I can then warn the user they need to pick another address.

In my controller, I have a method such as this:

```
public JsonResult IsEmailValid(int companyId, string customerNumber)
{            
  return Json(...);
}
```

To make this work, I will need to update my routes to point directly to `/Home/IsEmailValid` and the two parameters `{companyId}` and `{customerNumber}`. This seems like I'm "hacking" around in the routing system and I'm guessing perhaps there is a cleaner alternative.

Is there a "proper" or recommended way to accomplish this task?

EDIT: What I meant by the routes is that passing in extra parameter ({customerNumber}) in the URL (/Home/IsEmailValid/{companyId}/{customerNumber}) won't work with the default route mapping.

Comment: What do you mean "Update my routes to point directly to /Home/IsEmailValid" ? You could use something like jQuery Validation's remote attribute to accomplish what you describe.

Comment: If I make a GET to /Home/IsValidEmail/{companyId}/{customerNumber} it will not call the method I have listed there unless I update the routing table (to the best of my knowledge..it certainly doesn't seem to work). I will search for the Validation remote attribute for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to do that.

You're gonna have to implement your own method though like this :

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkCompanyEmail", function(value, element) {
    var email = value;
    var companyID = //get the companyID
    var result;
    //post the data to server side and process the result and return it
    return result;
}, "That company email is already taken.");
```

Then register your validation method :

```
$("#the-form").validate({
   rules: { email: { required: true, "checkCompanyEmail" : true } } 
});
```

PS. I don't understand why you need to "hack around" with routing for that.

Answer (score 0):

from the validate documentation under [remote method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote)

```
    remote: {
      url: "check-email.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        username: function() {
         return $("#username").val();
        }
      }
    }
```